# How to log LoggerMarker to specific file only?

Tags: java, logging, configuration, log4j, log4j2

I'm trying to achive the following using `log4j2`:

Log all general content to console, but log `MarkerFilter.FILTERED` only to a specific file, not to console.

```
<Configuration>
    <Appenders>
        <Console name="CONSOLE" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
            <ThresholdFilter level="INFO" onMatch="ACCEPT" onMismatch="DENY"/>
        </Console>


        <RollingFile name="FILTERED" fileName="filtered.txt" />
            <MarkerFilter marker="FILTERED" onMatch="ACCEPT" onMismatch="DENY"/>
        </RollingFile>
    </Appenders>

    <Loggers>
        <Root level="all">
            <AppenderRef ref="CONSOLE" />
            <AppenderRef ref="FILTERED" />
        </Root>
    </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

The following works in general, BUT logs any `FILTERED` content to console additionally.
But when I remove the `<AppenderRef ref="FILTERED" />` form `<root>` loggers, nothing is logged to the file anymore!

Answer (score 1):

How about using the marker filter on the console appender with a DENY action?

You can set the level on the appender-ref, so you don't need to use a `ThresholdFilter` for that.

```
<Configuration status="warn">
    <Appenders>
        <Console name="CONSOLE" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
            <MarkerFilter marker="FILTERED" onMatch="DENY" onMismatch="ACCEPT"/>
        </Console>

        <RollingFile name="FILTERED" fileName="filtered.txt" />
            <MarkerFilter marker="FILTERED" onMatch="ACCEPT" onMismatch="DENY"/>
        </RollingFile>
    </Appenders>

    <Loggers>
        <Root level="all">
            <AppenderRef ref="CONSOLE" level="info" />
            <AppenderRef ref="FILTERED" />
        </Root>
    </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```